# Adding Count Value to "qplot" histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am wondering how I can add the count value to the histogram graph which is plotted by `qplot`?

```
    qplot(cluster_name$km.out1.cluster, geom="histogram",binwidth = 0.5,
main = "Histogram for clusters Number", xlab = "cluster number", fill=I("blue")) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I tried to add

```
+ stat_bin(aes(y=..count..,label=..count..), geom="text", vjust=-.5, binwidth = 0.5)
```

however, this command will add a bunch of zeros on the x axis which is not what I want. I tried to remove `label` but got an error message. Please see picture of the result, below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent zero counts being labelled you can add an `ifelse` statement to `stat_bin` or `geom_text` which sets the label to an empty string for zero counts.

Using `mtcars` as example data try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

qplot(mtcars$mpg, geom="histogram",binwidth = 0.5,
      main = "Histogram for clusters Number", xlab = "cluster number", fill=I("blue")) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count..,label = ifelse(..count.. > 0, ..count.., "")), geom="text", vjust=-.5, binwidth = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, Stefan, it worked. Can you please also explain what exactly are we doing when we add "y=..count.." or "..count.. > 0, ..count.., "". I am not familiar with ".." (two dots) that you have used.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. As you used `..count..` in your code I thought you are familiar with that. Each stat layer like `stat_bin` or `stat_count` computes variables under the hood, e.g. the counts per bin. A list of the computed variables can be found on the help package of the stat or geom, e.g. ?stat_bin. To access these computed variables and use them like normal variables we use the notation `..NAME_OF_COMPUTED_VARIABLE..`.